# the same action when dispatched for the second time does not call the saga, while it does correctly in the first tie

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-redux, react-hooks, redux-saga

When the saga is being called on an action after the first load it is working correctly.
but when the same action is performed twice on the saga the action is dispatched but the saga never receives it.

```js
useEffect(() => {
  if (show) {
   updateTitle(message.title);
   if (!status || status === Status.Initiate) {
    createStatus();
   }
  }
  return () => {
   if (!show) {
    cleanup();
   }
  };

 }, [status]);
```

Comment: If the status variable does not change after the first call, then as its a dependency,  useEffect wont be triggered. See [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html#tip-optimizing-performance-by-skipping-effects)

Comment: Which does `updateTitle()` do? Which part of the state will it update?

Comment: @BenSmith `useEffect` is being triggered and and in fact I can see the action function being called in the redux, except there is nothing happening after the action is dispatched. communication missing between dispatch and saga.

@wentjun `updateTitle` updates some different part of the state.

Comment: I'd suggest adding your saga and reducer code to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below process solved my issue.

Turns out, in the runtime, if some saga fails to execute, that saga is never called again, that means if any action is generated for that saga it is just ignored.

To check if the saga is failing during the runtime, you can wrap the body of saga inside a try catch block.

```js
function* failingSaga() {
  try {
  
    // saga-body
  } catch(e) {
    console.log(e);
  }
}
```

this will help in getting to know what the exception is.